# Don't know how to use csv-writer to write a csv file row by row after API call

Tags: node.js, csv, promise

My use case is the following. I have a node.js application that makes API calls throttled by an external library `limiter`. I then make API calls at a rate of 27 calls/per second until I am done looping over a whole array that contains one parameter I need to pass to the API. Once I get the response from the API I want to save this data in a csv file.

My idea is to write the csv file row by row once I get the result from the API. I am using [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer) for that.

According to the docs

"You can keep writing records into the same file by calling writeRecords multiple times (but need to wait for the fulfilment of the promise of the previous writeRecords call)."

`Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => csvWriter.writeRecords(records1))
    .then(() => csvWriter.writeRecords(records2))`

I've been also thinking about trying to make the code wait till the API calls finish and prompt the csv file to be written then, however, I don't know how to do it. I couldn't find any examples online about something similar. All of them seem to start from an object/Array. I've also tried to add a catch for any exceptions thrown even though it's not advised in the docs. Something along these lines.

```
          Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => csvWriter.writeRecords(outp))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is my code:

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createArrayCsvWriter;  

 var limiter = new RateLimiter(27, 'second', true);

let final = [xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx, ..... ]

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    header: ['NAME'],
    path: 'out.csv'
});

let outp = []
final.forEach((item, index) => {

//limit the API calls according to the limiter defined above
  limiter.removeTokens(1, () => {


    ExternalAPIcall({ number: item}, (error, response) => {
       if (error) {
         console.error(error)
       } else {
         console.log(response.status_message)

        output.push(response.status_message)]

         const records = output.map(NAME => [NAME])
              csvWriter.writeRecords(records)



       }
     })


   })
 })
```

I would expect the file to be written line by line and I could then use append: `true` to overwrite the file if needed as indicated in the docs. However, this error is thrown.

(node:3540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 86)
(node:3540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ArrayCsvStringifier.getCsvLine (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-stringifiers/abstract.js:19:14)
    at Array.from.record (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-stringifiers/abstract.js:14:61)
    at Function.from (native)
    at ArrayCsvStringifier.stringifyRecords (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-stringifiers/abstract.js:14:32)
    at CsvWriter. (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-writer.js:24:55)
    at Generator.next ()
    at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-writer.js:7:71
    at new Promise ()
    at __awaiter (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-writer.js:3:12)
    at CsvWriter.writeRecords (/Users/xxx/Desktop/nodexcel/node_modules/csv-writer/dist/lib/csv-writer.js:22:16)
(node:3540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 88)

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
J.

---

SOLVED:
The issue was that writeRecords is expecting > like Array> and I was passing passing an Array. https://github.com/ryu1kn/csv-writer/blob/86a57cae5d68f91d738318aff1de3b6d55d6b718/README.md#csvwriterwriterecordsrecords, This bit solved it.

const records = llenar.map(NAME => [NAME])
              csvWriter.writeRecords(records)

I have updated the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your file to be written line by line then you have to wait for those promises, `Promise.all` will not help you.

However you can make the promises run sequentialy using the `.reduce` method.

You can try the code below:

```js
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
var createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createArrayCsvWriter;
var limiter = new RateLimiter(27, 'second', true);

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  header: ['NAME'],
  path: './out.csv'
});

/** Mocked module - you can delete this */
const nexmo = {
  numberInsight: {
    get: (item, cb) => {
      if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
        cb = () => {}
      }
      let msg = {
        status: 1,
        status_message: `${item.number} - have passed`
      };
      cb(null, msg);
    }
  }
}

var final = ['john', 'mike', 'elise', 'valentine']

final = final.reduce((accumulator, item, index) => {

  return accumulator.then(() => {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      limiter.removeTokens(1, (err, remainingReq) => {

        if (err) {
          resolve(Promise.resolve(err.message));
        } else {

          nexmo.numberInsight.get({
            level: 'basic',
            number: item
          }, (error, response) => {

            if (error) {
              resolve(Promise.resolve(error.message));
            } else {

              csvWriter.writeRecords([
                [response.status_message]
              ]).then(() => {
                resolve(response.status_message)
              }).catch(writerErr => {
                resolve(writerErr.message);
              })

            }

          })

        }

      })

    })

  })
}, Promise.resolve());

final.then(lastPromiseResponse => {

  console.log('final', lastPromiseResponse)

}).catch(err => {
  console.log('final err', err);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @darklightcode. It returns this: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: csvWriter is not defined. With regards to your comment on limiter. It should be a function, doesn't it ? As per [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter)

Comment: @JavilondoRamires just to make sure, you did replace `final.forEach` with the above code, right ? I've changed only that part of your code ! Or you can make a fiddle with the code you've tried.

Comment: Yep I did, This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7emxyc9/) for reference. Thanks

Comment: You didn't, i have updated my answer with the complete version.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks very much. I've tried and still it didn't work "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)" . UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: record.map is not a function

Comment: The error it's telling you what is wrong `TypeError: record.map is not a function`,  currently `record.map` doesn't exist in the above code, check your unposted code. As for this line `outp[index, 0] = response.status_message` , check my updated code, i replaced it, `outp[index, 0]` will always evaluate as `outp[0]`. You might want to check `ExternalAPIcall` function though, for that `record.map`.

Comment: I've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rkeswjh/1/). The API responds fine, when I console.log the result it prints the result fine. (Print ```success``` coming from ```response.status_message```)

Comment: I have update my code with a fully working demo. Here is the sandbox link https://repl.it/repls/LuxuriousElegantTrialsoftware

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. I've also updated my question with the working code

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code reference.
Here I have taken keys from JSON object for example purpose.

```
   let someObject = yourArray[0] // JSON array
   let csvHeader = [] 
   for(let key in someObject) {
     csvHeader.push({ id: key, title: key });
   }
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        path: csvFilePath,
        header: csvHeader
    });
    return await csvWriter.writeRecords(yourArray);
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your time. Unfortunately this doesn't work. This API works synchronously and therefore once I use await it says that "await is only valid in async function". Thanks very much, though

Comment: Yes, you will need to wrap the code in async method as await is used

Answer (score 0):

Neither the updated code snippet in Javilondo's question post nor darklightcode's answer seem to be waiting for the fulfilment of the promise `writeRecords` returns before invoking the next `writeRecords` call. That can cause data loss if underlying stream cannot write to the file fast enough.

We can write something like below, to make sure `writeRecords` gets called after the previous call is finished. Since I used [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), Node.js v8+ is required. (If you use lower version of Node, just write it on your own.)

```js
const {RateLimiter} = require('limiter');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createArrayCsvWriter;
const {promisify} = require('util');

const limiter = new RateLimiter(27, 'second');

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    header: ['NAME'],
    path: 'out.csv'
});

const removeTokens = promisify(limiter.removeTokens.bind(limiter));
const callExternalApi = promisify(ExternalAPIcall);

final.reduce(async (promise, item) => {
    await promise;
    await removeTokens(1);

    const {status_message} = await callExternalApi({number: item});
    const records = [[status_message]];
    await csvWriter.writeRecords(records);
}, Promise.resolve()).catch(e => {
    console.error(e.stack);
});
```

I ran this snippet with defining `ExternalAPIcall` and `final` as follows:

```js
const ExternalAPIcall = (params, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(null, {status_message: `success: ${params.number}`});
    }, 0);
};

const final = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```